# Can snakemake resolve ambiguous rules by specifying intermediate output files?

Tags: python, workflow, snakemake

Say I create the following snakemake setup:

```
rule all_a:
    input:
        'a.txt',
        'output.txt'

rule all_b:
    input:
        'b.txt',
        'output.txt'

rule gen_a:
    input:
        'input.txt'
    output:
        'a.txt'


rule gen_b:
    input:
        'input.txt'
    output:
        'b.txt'


rule process_a:
    input:
        'a.txt'
    output:
        'output.txt'


rule process_b:
    input:
        'b.txt'
    output:
        'output.txt'
```

If I try to run `snakemake all_a`, I get an ambiguous rule error, since there are two rules that can produce `output.txt`. However, I would think that because `all_a` explicitly specifies `a.txt`, then snakemake should be able to figure out which "branch" of the DAG I want.  But actually it complains bc in principle, it has enough information to execute both branches of the DAG.  Is there a way for me to explicitly specify which path to take?

Answer (score 0):

Wildcards are evaluated individually, and inputs often can and will come from different sources, so this is not something Snakemake innately tries to restrict.

I would use the [ruleorder](http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/latest/snakefiles/rules.html#handling-ambiguous-rules) limitation within Snakemake.

Snakemake is promiscuous in this regards. If Snakemake can, and it hasn't been told otherwise, it will. We refine this by restricting the scope of rules involved (limit of 1 rule capable of producing output.txt), or by providing ways for Snakemake resolve ambiguities (ruleorder).